# How to pull Docker image from a private repository using AWS Batch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch

I'm using AWS Batch and my Docker image is hosted on private Nexus repo. I'm trying to create the Job Definition but i can't find anywere how to specify the Repo Credentials like we did with a Task Definition in ECS.

I tried to manually specify it in the Json like that :

```
{
"command": ["aws", "s3", "ls"],
"image": "nexus-docker-repo.xxxxx.xxx/my-image",
"memory": 1024,
"vcpus": 1,
"repositoryCredentials": {
"credentialsParameter": "ARN_OF_CREDENTIALS"
},
"jobRoleArn" : "ARN_OF_THE_JOB"
}
```

But when i apply the changes the parameter credentialsParameter was removed . I think that it's not supported.

So how to pull an image from a private repo with AWS Batch ? Is it possible ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see the option `repositoryCredentials` either in the batch job definition.

A secure option could be

1. Generate the config.json for [docker login](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry/authentication)
2. Place that file in s3
3. Generate an IAM role that has access to that file.
4. Create a [compute environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environments.html) with a
   [Launch Template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html) and user data to download the config.json
5. Run the jobs with that compute environment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was able to do it by modifying the file /etc/ecs/ecs.config

If the file is not there you have to create it.

Then I had to add these 2 lines in that file :

```
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=docker
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA={"https://index.docker.io/v1/":{"username":"admin","password":"admin","email":"admin@example.com "}}
```

Then i had to restart the ECS agent :

```
sudo systemctl restart ecs ## for the Amazon ECS-optimized Amazon Linux 2 AMI
Or
sudo stop ecs && sudo start ecs ## for For the Amazon ECS-optimized Amazon Linux AMI
```